# django REST swagger function based api does not have input PARAMETERS

Tags: django, rest, api, parameters, swagger

I am trying to do Django REST function based API with swagger following these instructions.

https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs

However, I am unable to get any parameters shown in the function. This is the screenshot of swagger NOT displaying any parameters.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LCv3.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/P30Rd.jpg

UPDATE:This is how I want to achieve with the parameters https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA0aX.jpg

Here is my API code, I want to have "name" parameters shown in swagger
https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/api.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def test_post(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: This API deletes/uninstalls a device.
    parameters:
      - name: name
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form
    """
    name = request.POST.get('name')

    return Response("Data Saved!", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This is the difference on my pip freeze library with the working example of django-rest-swagger-docs https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5c328b9e4a6ff3f86676fe930440dd2

What is the problem, you can view the whole source code in gitlab. Thanks.

Comment: You should click on `Try it out` and it will show you your parameters :), you will then see your `DRFApi` url address and you can go to it and inspect it

Comment: i dont see anything on DRF https://imgur.com/a/n5CDU. I updated a screenshot which appears to work well in the example https://imgur.com/a/cLYNF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in readme

```
*Input parameters for function based views do not appear:* You might be using
    incompatible versions, try using `djangorestframework==3.5.3` and `django-rest-swagger==2.1.1`.
```

I updated to djangorestframework==3.5.3 and it works